# vbsScript remove space echo

Tags: vbscript

Hello im making unhide usb files i modify konboot usb installer to usb unhide

**CMD**
cscript //Nologo  USB.vbs>unhide.bat

```
Wscript.Echo "attrib -s -h -r /s /d "& SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID,"\*.*"
```

the output 
attrib -s -h -r /s /d F:(have space here)*.*

i need no space on F:(Here)*.*

my final output i want
attrib -s -h -r /s /d F:*.*

**vbscript**

```
Dim query 
Dim WMBIObj 
Dim AllDiskDrives 
Dim SingleDiskDrive 
Dim AllLogicalDisks 
Dim SingleLogicalDisk 
Dim AllPartitions 
Dim Partition 
Dim result
Dim textmsg
Dim wshShell
Dim FileObj
Dim Counter

set FileObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set wshShell = wscript.createObject("wscript.shell")
Set WMBIObj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set AllDiskDrives = WMBIObj.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'") ' 
For Each SingleDiskDrive In AllDiskDrives 
    counter = counter + 1
    query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + SingleDiskDrive.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" 
    Set AllPartitions = WMBIObj.ExecQuery(query) 
    For Each Partition In AllPartitions 
        query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + Partition.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
        Set AllLogicalDisks = WMBIObj.ExecQuery (query) 
        For Each SingleLogicalDisk In AllLogicalDisks  

            textmsg =   "============================================" & VbCr & _ 
                        "DeviceID: " & SingleDiskDrive.DeviceID & VbCr & _ 
                        "Logical Drive: "  & SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID & VbCr & _ 
                        "Model: " & SingleDiskDrive.Model & VbCr & _ 
                        "Manufacturer: " & SingleDiskDrive.Manufacturer & VbCr & _
                        "============================================" & VbCr & _ 
                        "Would you like to use this drive as destination?" & VbCr & _ 
                        "Warning, disk data may be overwritten"
            result = MsgBox(textmsg, vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "USB")

            if result = vbOk Then
                        WScript.Echo "echo DeviceID: " & SingleDiskDrive.DeviceID  
                        WScript.Echo "echo Logical Drive: "  & SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID
                        WScript.Echo "echo Model: " & SingleDiskDrive.Model
                        WScript.Echo "echo Manufacturer: " & SingleDiskDrive.Manufacturer
                        Wscript.Echo "attrib -s -h -r /s /d "& SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID,"\*.*"
                        wshShell.Run "unhide.bat"
                        WScript.quit 

                MsgBox "Your USB is ready!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "USB"
                WScript.quit 
            End If
        Next
    Next 
Next 
if counter = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No USB disks detected or unknown error!", vbCritical + vbOkOnly, "USB"
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
Wscript.Echo "attrib -s -h -r /s /d "& SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID,"\*.*"
```

You need to concatenate the strings `"attrib -s -h -r /s /d "`, `SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID` and `"\*.*"`

You are using `,` instead of `&` to concatenate the second and third strings. It should actually be:

```
Wscript.Echo "attrib -s -h -r /s /d "& SingleLogicalDisk.DeviceID & "\*.*"
```

When  you use `,` instead of `&`, the third string is considered as another argument to the `echo` method. So, it adds a space between the arguments in the output.

From: [Echo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7(v=vs.84).aspx)

> Each displayed item is separated with a space character.